# Error 431 Request Header Fields Too Large after enabling Msal authentication to app

Tags: http-error, msal.js, react-aad-msal

Due to loo long cookie send in request header azure webapp returning 431 error ie request headers field too large. I read a lot of issues on Github but nothing working. I post my config :

```
const config = {
      auth: {
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+process.env.REACT_APP_TENANT,
      clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_POST_LOGOUT,
      validateAuthority: true,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
```